# Show current location without pin

Tags: ios, objective-c

How show current location without pin(or blur dot) and show all others locations with pins?

My code: http://pastebin.com/dJzEZMHv

Comment: You can paste code straight into your question. Just hit CMD-K to format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

add the following code to the

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation method

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil; 

}
```

Comment: Ohh! It works! Thank YOU!